# Can QGIS create Vector Polygons from Raster Data?

Tags: qgis, raster, vectorization

I normally use Esri, am new to QGIS, and don't know a lot of terminology and definitions.

I am working with georeferenced geologic maps. Each formation is coded with a different color or color pattern.

Is it possible for QGIS 2.18.12 to analyze these data, identify areas with that particular spectral signature, and then use the analysis to create vector polygons?

Hand digitizing is too time consuming.

Comment: Yes..  Raster ==> Conversion ==>  Polygonize.   Do the different color codes represent raster values or value ranges that can be isolated say with raster calculator in QGIS?